# RPG Inventory System Tutorial C++

Tags: c++, inventory

Hey guy I'm wondering if there is a tutorial or example code for a C++ RPG inventory system. I've surfed the website and I only discovered to make two classes, item and inventory and to use each of them for item's detail and holding the items in a linked list.

This is what I have so far..

```
using namespace std;

int maxWeight;

class inventory {  //manages the entire inventory
public:
    inventory();
    inventory::inventory(int defaultWeight = maxWeight);

private:
    int maxWeight = 100;


};

class item {  //holds the details about a particular item
public:
    item();
    item(char* name, double weight);    
private:
    char* name;
    double weight;
};
```

I'm hoping my long search for such a tutorial can end..

Thank you.

Comment: You can create a class called Inventory. In this class, there is a linked list of Items. You can have attributes such as maximum size of inventory, etc. Try it out first and ask when you face difficulties

Comment: First of all I want to say thank you for replying. The program I'm trying to write is for a hw assignment. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to make it to a lecture that spoke specifically about this project. Anyways, I'm supposed to write a program that doesn't require UI for the player. Instead, it's simply printed but the professor wants to see the details of an inventory system.

Comment: The first steps are to create the "item: class with a constructor that will take in a char* name and a double weight but I don't understand how this will help in the later coding. I mean.. I understand that constructors are used to set a default value but i don't know how it would be used to describe the name of an item.
The next class I'm supposed to build is "inventory." This class is supposed to have a linked list that will carry all the items.
I have tried searching and learning these topics, but I can't manage to construct a code that meet my professor's specifications.

Comment: char* name would be the name of your item. double weight is the weight of your item. Your inventory probably will only allow a maximum amount of weight. There are many existing versions of linked lists that you can look into to help you.

Comment: This is what I have written up so far. I'm hoping that I could build up from what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, from what I understand so far, what you are looking for is a linked list in your inventory to store all the items. Find out how a linked list works and go ahead from there. You will probably need to

1. Add items (check the weight of your current linked list prior to adding the item).
2. Remove items.
3. Print whatever is in the linked list.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the help. I will try to work on it and see if I can get anything going. I would give you a big thumbs up or some kind of extra points for this site but I don't have any rep points..